# DirectShow: IVMRWindowlessControl::SetVideoPosition stride(?)

Tags: directshow

I have my own video source and using VMR7. When I use 24 color depth, my graph contains Color Space Converter filter which converts 24 bits to ARGB32. Everything works fine. When I use 32 bit color depth, my image looks desintegrated. In this case my source produces RGB32 images and passes them directly to VMR7 without color conversion. During window sizing I noticed that when destination height is changing the image becomes "integrated" (normal) in some specific value of destination height. I do not know where is the problem. Here are the example photos: http://talbot.szm.com/desintegrated.jpg and http://talbot.szm.com/integrated.jpg 
  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for a MediaType change in your `FillBuffer` method.

```
HRESULT hr = pSample->GetMediaType((AM_MEDIA_TYPE**)&pmt);
if (S_OK == hr)
{
    SetMediaType(pmt);
    DeleteMediaType(pmt);
}
```

Depending on your graphic you get different width for your buffer. This means, you connect with an image width of 1000 pixels but with the first sample you get a new width for your buffer. In my example it was 1024px.

[image]

Now you have the new image size in the `BitmapInfoHeader.biWidth` and got the old size in the `VideoInfoHeader.rcSource`. So one line of your image has a size of 1024 pixels and not 1000 pixels. If you don't remember this you can sometimes get pictures like you.